# Как добавить сервис в NixOS?

Tags: linux

часть файла configuration.nix:

```
    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
                tgt
        ];

systemd.services = {
                tgtd = {
                        enable = true;
                };
        };
```

при запуске службы командой systemctl start tgtd появляется ошибка:

> nixos systemd[1]: tgtd.service: Service has no ExecStart=, ExecStop=,
> or SuccessAction=. Refusing.

Я понимаю, что можно прописать все эти настройки, но они лежат готовые в файле /nix/store/хэш/etc/systemd/system/tgtd.service. Вот так выглядят:

```
[Unit]
Description=iSCSI target framework daemon
Documentation=man: tgtd(8)
After=network.target

# On systems without virtual consoles, don't start any getty. Note
# that serial gettys are covered by serial-getty@.service, not this
# unit.
ConditionPathExists=/etc/tgt/targets.conf

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=TGTD_CONFIG=/etc/tgt/targets.conf

ExecStart=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgtd
ExecStartPost=/nix/store/vr96j3cxj75xsczl8pzrgsv1k57hcxyp-coreutils-8.31/bin/sleep 5
ExecStartPost=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgtadm --op update --mode sys --name State -v offline
ExecStartPost=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgtadm --op update --mode sys --name State -v ready
ExecStartPost=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgt-admin -e -c ${TGTD_CONFIG}

ExecReload=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgt-admin --update ALL -f -c ${TGTD_CONFIG}

ExecStop=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgtadm --op update --mode sys --name State -v offline
ExecStop=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgt-admin --offline ALL
ExecStop=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgt-admin --update ALL -c /dev/null -f
ExecStop=/nix/store/dkyyq75mz2cf7zcqjvydvgg5965lggh7-tgt-1.0.79/bin/tgtadm  --op delete --mode system

# Exit code: 107 tgtd not running


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Можно ли явно указать путь до этих настроек?